# Как вернуться обратно в меню tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Написал код, при открытие которого появляется меню с кнопкой сообщения:

```
from tkinter import *


def message():
    
    destroy_object = [btn_msg]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()
    lbl.configure(text='Сообщения')
    btn_back = Button(window, text='Назад')
    btn_back.grid(column=0, row=1)


window = Tk()
window.title('Тест')
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    
lbl = Label(window, text='Меню')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn_msg = Button(window, text='Сообщения', command=message)
btn_msg.grid(column=0, row=1)


window.mainloop()
```

При нажатии на кнопку все перерисовывается и переходит якобы в раздел сообщения где есть кнопка назад, как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку назад выходило из функции и появлялся прежний вид меню?
Я пробовал меню заносить в функцию:

```
from tkinter import *


def message():

    destroy_object = [btn_msg]
    for object_name in destroy_object:
        object_name.destroy()
    lbl.configure(text='Сообщения')
    btn_back = Button(window, text='Назад')
    btn_back.grid(column=0, row=1)

def menu():

    lbl = Label(window, text='Меню')
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    btn_msg = Button(window, text='Сообщения', command=message)
    btn_msg.grid(column=0, row=1)

window = Tk()
window.title('Тест')
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

menu() 

window.mainloop()
```

но выдавало ошибку `NameError`

Подскажите как реализовать данную идею? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации вашей идеи лучше использовать классы, вместо функций.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

class MainMenu():
    def __init__(self,tk,tk_title):

        def messages(event):
            self.tk.destroy()
            Messages(tkinter.Tk(), 'Сообщения')
            
        self.tk = tk
        self.tk.title(tk_title)
        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        self.lbl = Label(self.tk, text='Меню')
        self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.btn_msg = Button(self.tk, text='Сообщения')
        self.btn_msg.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.btn_msg.bind('<Button-1>', messages)

        self.tk.mainloop()



class Messages():
    def __init__(self, tk, tk_title):

        def back(event):
            self.tk.destroy()
            MainMenu(tkinter.Tk(), 'Меню')

        self.tk = tk
        self.tk.title(tk_title)
        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        self.lbl = Label(self.tk, text='Сообщения')
        self.lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.btn_back = Button(self.tk, text='Назад')
        self.btn_back.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.btn_back.bind('<Button-1>', back)

        self.tk.mainloop()


MainMenu(tkinter.Tk(), 'Меню')
```

`self` - означает, что объект принадлежит конкретному классу и может использоваться только в нем

---

Если вам принципиально делать через функции, то вам нужно объявить компоненты, а затем в функциях, изменять их значения и параметры:

```
from tkinter import *

def message():
    global lbl, btn
    lbl['text'] ='Сообщения'
    btn['text'] = 'Назад'
    btn['command'] = menu

def menu():
    global lbl, btn
    lbl.['text'] = 'Меню'
    btn['text'] = 'Сообщения'
    btn['command'] = message

window = Tk()
window.title('Тест')
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

btn = Button(window, text='Сообщения', command=message)
btn.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl = Label(window, text='Меню')
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

menu() 

window.mainloop()
```